# Deserialize json string having multiple special characters in C#

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

Following is my json string:

```
[
  {"Sname":"wordpress_Site_Url","Settings":"http://www.mywebsite.com","lab":false},
  {"Sname":"wordpress_template","Settings":"[vc_row][vc_column width="2/3"][vc_column_text]  &nbsp; {{{description}}}  &nbsp;  [/vc_column_text][/vc_column][vc_column width="1/3" css=".vc_custom_1438623014033{border-color: #dbead5 !important;}"] [gravityform id="14" title="false" description="false" ajax="true" field_values="downloadFileID={{downloadURL}}"][/vc_column][/vc_row][vc_row][vc_column][vc_column_text]  [/vc_column_text][/vc_column][/vc_row]","lab":true,"selected":false},
  {"Sname":"dummy","Settings":"abc","lab":false},
  {"Sname":"testing","Settings":"ssds","lab":false}
]
```

I want to write a function that takes key `Sname` in json above as parameter and return the value `Setting` in json above from this json string.

Escaping doesn't help, before deserializing

Comment: from where you are reading this json

Comment: i have saved it on my database as a string.

Comment: this JSON is invalid !

Comment: validate your Json https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: The actual problem is the template saved as a value for key "wordpress_template" inside my json. I am already using a temporary solution for this.. it replace the Setting : '' for key "wordpress_template" and then deserialize works perfect. I am trying to find a permanent solution for this because i need to it on many places

Answer (score 0):

If you have influence on the way how the Settings object is serialized I would recommend you to serialize it properly. Otherwise you would have to do awful things to get it to work. Something like:

```
    class MyResultClass
    {
        public string Sname { get; set; }
        public string Settings { get; set; }
    }

    private MyResultClass Convert(string str)
    {
        var newStr = str.Replace("\"Settings\"", "VERYUNIQUEKEYWORD")
            .Replace("\"Sname\"", "ANOTHERKEYWORD")
            .Replace("\"", "QUOTE")
            .Replace("VERYUNIQUEKEYWORD", "\"Settings\"")
            .Replace("ANOTHERKEYWORD","\"Sname\"")
            .Replace(":QUOTE",":\"")
            .Replace("QUOTE,","\","); 

        var myObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyResultClass>(newStr);
        myObj.Settings = myObj.Settings.Replace("QUOTE", "\"");
        return myObj;
    }
```

Please note that this is NOT my recommendation.

Answer (score -1):

Before saving your JSON to your DATABASE you need to serialize your JSON string.
Afterwords you can easily Deserialize your JSON.

Comment: Why do you want to serialize a JSON string? To get a string?

Comment: @SirRufo because this JSON contains double quote in string, so need to store with slash double quote. That's the reason, got invalid JSON

Comment: You mean **back**slash double quote like *\"* - why didn't you write that in your answer? Serialize a JSON string does not make sense

Comment: @SirRufo Yes BackSlash, Serialize JSON automatically add required BackSlashes, No Need to do it manually. Hope you will remove your negative vote.

Comment: @SirRufo Thanks Pal